# Dog has a lump on eyelid

Tags: dogs

This morning I was petting my dog and noticed a small lump on his lower eyelid. It looks like the size of a large zit on a person but it's all under the skin and there isn't hair that close to his eye so I don't think it's an ingrown hair.

The soonest the vet will see me is 2 weeks out and they tend to reschedule for later dates most of the time. So it's not likely I'll be able to take him in to get a proper diagnostic.

He is a 10 year old beagle/basset mix.

[image: eyw lump]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you what it is, but I'm pretty sure that it can wait 2 weeks.

My own dog has a strong predisposition towards skin tags all over his body, and once even got one on his eye lid. It looked different than what your dog has, but I think the overall situation was very similar.

Such things usually develop slowly and stay benign most of the time, so there's no rush.

However, if your dog rubs the eye a lot with his paw or on carpets or furniture, it's a clear sign that it's bothering him (could be itchy or painful). In that case, you should call your vet, maybe even send them pictures, and ask for advice and possible treatments you can do at home.

If the lumb swells so much that it interferes with the function of the eyelid - either by stopping the lid from fully closing or by bringing the eye lashes into contact with the eyeball - you should call your vet, explain the situation and insist on an emergency treatment. If the eye is irritated by drying out or by the eye lashes, it can cause lasting damage and even blindness.